# How to embed request level objects to @Context

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

In embedded Jersey I can register a `Binder` to put in some resources that I can eventually access using `@Context`

However, those things I put in are more global and not on a per request level.  I do know I can do it with some property mapping, but I would rather do it through `@Context` with class like `Response foo(@Context HttpServletRequest)`

I tried the `setRequestScopedInitializer()` but it does not put them in as expected and following their example with the `Ref` gives me a null pointer exception

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I eventually did it, but I don't like that I used a named property

`RoutingContext` was the type I wanted to inject

```
public class RoutingContextFactory implements
Supplier<RoutingContext> {

@Inject
private ContainerRequest request;

@Override
public RoutingContext get() {

    return (RoutingContext) request.getProperty(RoutingContext.class.getName());
}
}
```

My binder

```
public class MyBinder extends AbstractBinder {

@Override
protected void configure() {

    bindFactory(RoutingContextFactory.class)
        .to(RoutingContext.class)
        .proxy(true)
        .proxyForSameScope(false)
        .in(RequestScoped.class);

}

}
```

Initialized by

```
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = ResourceConfig.forApplicationClass(applicationClass);
    resourceConfig.register(new MyBinder());
```

Loaded by

```
    final ContainerRequest request = new ContainerRequest(...
    request.setProperty(RoutingContext.class.getName(), routingContext);
```

Used by

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello(
    @Context final RoutingContext routingContext) {

    return "Hello" 
        + routingContext;

}
```

I still wish there was a way for me to just go `request.register(routingContext)`. I opened up https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3682 for this.